# How to check edittext's text is email address or not?

Tags: android, android-edittext, email-validation

how to check the text of `edittext` is email address or not without using `javascript` and regular expression?
Here I used `inputtype="textEmailAddress"` this is working but no error message is display.

Comment: Surely PointerNull's answer below is the reasonable, modern, answer here??

Comment: @JoeBlow yes i agree, but there is a limited amount of time that the "asker" can change the agreed answer....

Answer (score 240, accepted):

```
/**
 * method is used for checking valid email id format.
 * 
 * @param email
 * @return boolean true for valid false for invalid
 */
public static boolean isEmailValid(String email) {
    String expression = "^[\\w\\.-]+@([\\w\\-]+\\.)+[A-Z]{2,4}$";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(expression, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(email);
    return matcher.matches();
}
```

Pass your edit text string in this function .

for right email verification you need server side authentication

---

**Note** there is now a built-in method in Android, see answers below.

Comment: `String` implements `CharSequence` so I think the cast from `email` to `inputStr` is redundant.

Comment: With the introduction of new top level domains that are longer than 2-4 characters, this needs to be updated.  Simply replace the 
{2.4}" with a "+".  (e.g. joe@century21.realtor)

Comment: Don't use regular expressions when validating e-mail addresses (see http://stackoverflow.com/a/201378/2003763)

Answer (score 438):

On Android 2.2+ use this:

```java
boolean isEmailValid(CharSequence email) {
   return android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email).matches();
}
```

for example:

```java
EditText emailid = (EditText) loginView.findViewById(R.id.login_email);
String getEmailId = emailid.getText().toString();

// Check if email id is valid or not
if (!isEmailValid(getEmailId)){
    new CustomToast().Show_Toast(getActivity(), loginView,
        "Your Email Id is Invalid.");
}
```

Answer (score 13):

Please follow the following Steps

Step 1 :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText_email"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView_email"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:hint="Email Adderess"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView_email"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:text="Email Validation Example" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Step 2:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.widget.EditText;
```

Step 3:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private EditText email;

private String valid_email;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    initilizeUI();
}

/**
 * This method is used to initialize UI Components
 */
private void initilizeUI() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_email);

    email.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                int count) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Is_Valid_Email(email); // pass your EditText Obj here.
        }

        public void Is_Valid_Email(EditText edt) {
            if (edt.getText().toString() == null) {
                edt.setError("Invalid Email Address");
                valid_email = null;
            } else if (isEmailValid(edt.getText().toString()) == false) {
                edt.setError("Invalid Email Address");
                valid_email = null;
            } else {
                valid_email = edt.getText().toString();
            }
        }

        boolean isEmailValid(CharSequence email) {
            return android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email)
                    .matches();
        } // end of TextWatcher (email)
    });

}

}
```

Answer (score 12):

I wrote a library that extends EditText which supports natively some validation methods and is actually very flexible.

Current, as I write,  **natively** supported (through **xml attributes**) validation methods are:

1. **regexp**: for custom regexp
2. **numeric**: for an only numeric field
3. **alpha**: for an alpha only field
4. **alphaNumeric**: guess what?
5. **email**: checks that the field is a valid email
6. **creditCard**: checks that the field contains a valid credit card using Luhn Algorithm
7. **phone**: checks that the field contains a valid phone number
8. **domainName**: checks that field contains a valid domain name ( always passes the test in API Level < 8 )
9. **ipAddress**: checks that the field contains a valid ip address
   webUrl: checks that the field contains a valid url ( always passes the test in API Level < 8 )
10. **nocheck**: It does not check anything. (Default)

You can check it out here: https://github.com/vekexasia/android-form-edittext

Hope you enjoy it :)

In the page I linked you'll be able to find also an example for email validation. I'll copy the relative snippet here:

```
<com.andreabaccega.widget.FormEditText
       style="@android:style/Widget.EditText"
       whatever:test="email"
       android:id="@+id/et_email"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:hint="@string/hint_email"
       android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
       />
```

There is also a test app showcasing the library possibilities.

This is a screenshot of the app validating the email field.

[image: email validation done thorugh xml+library]

Answer (score 8):

As mentioned in one of the answers you can use the `Patterns` class as below:

```
public final static boolean isValidEmail(CharSequence target) {
    if (target == null) 
        return false;

    return android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(target).matches();
}
```

By chance if you are even supporting API level less than 8, then you can simply copy the `Patterns.java` file into your project and reference it. You can get the source code for `Patterns.java` from [this link](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.3.5_r1/android/util/Patterns.java)

Answer (score 5):

In your case you can use the `android.util.Patterns package`.

```
EditText email = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.user_email);

if(Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email.getText().toString()).matches())
    Toast.makeText(this, "Email is VALID.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
else
    Toast.makeText(this, "Email is INVALID.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Answer (score 3):

The following code should be useful to you.

```
String email;
check.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {


                public void onClick(View arg0) {

                    checkEmail(email);
                    if (checkMail) {
                        System.out.println("Valid mail Id");
                    }
                }
            });

        }
    }

    public static boolean checkEmail(String email) {

        Pattern EMAIL_ADDRESS_PATTERN = Pattern
                .compile("[a-zA-Z0-9+._%-+]{1,256}" + "@"
                        + "[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,64}" + "(" + "."
                        + "[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,25}" + ")+");
        return EMAIL_ADDRESS_PATTERN.matcher(email).matches();
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

For Email Address validation try this simple and easy code.

```
    String email = inputEmail.getText().toString().trim();

    if (!Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email).matches())
    {
        inputEmail.setError("Enter Valid Email Address");
        inputEmail.requestFocus();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

here email is your email-id.

```
  public boolean validateEmail(String email) {

    Pattern pattern;
    Matcher matcher;
    String EMAIL_PATTERN = "^[_A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@[A-Za-z0-9]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$";
    pattern = Pattern.compile(EMAIL_PATTERN);
    matcher = pattern.matcher(email);
    return matcher.matches();

    }
```

Comment: The author of the current email RFC, John Klensin, has an email address you reject. It contains a + sign.

Answer (score 2):

[Apache Commons Validator](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-validator/download_validator.cgi) can be used as mentioned in the other answers.

Step:1)Download the jar file from [here](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-validator/download_validator.cgi)

Step:2)Add it into your project libs

The import:

```
import org.apache.commons.validator.routines.EmailValidator;
```

The code:

```
String email = "myName@example.com";
boolean valid = EmailValidator.getInstance().isValid(email);
```

and to allow local addresses::

```
boolean allowLocal = true;
boolean valid = EmailValidator.getInstance(allowLocal).isValid(email);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
public boolean isValidEmail(String email) {
    return (PatternsCompat.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email).matches());
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A simple method

```
    private boolean isValidEmail(String email)
{
    String emailRegex ="^[_A-Za-z0-9-\\+]+(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$";
    if(email.matches(emailRegex))
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public static boolean isEmailValid(String email) {
    boolean isValid = false;

    String expression = "^(([\\w-]+\\.)+[\\w-]+|([a-zA-Z]{1}|[\\w-]{2,}))@"
            + "((([0-1]?[0-9]{1,2}|25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9])\\.([0-1]?"
            + "[0-9]{1,2}|25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9])\\."
            + "([0-1]?[0-9]{1,2}|25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9])\\.([0-1]?"
            + "[0-9]{1,2}|25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9])){1}|"
            + "([a-zA-Z]+[\\w-]+\\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,4})$";
    // "^[\\w\\.-]+@([\\w\\-]+\\.)+[A-Z]{2,4}$";
    CharSequence inputStr = email;

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(expression, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(inputStr);
    if (!matcher.matches()) {
        isValid = true;
    }
    return isValid;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
   I Hope this code is beneficial for you

    public class Register extends Activity 
      {
       EditText FirstName, PhoneNo, EmailId,weight;
       Button Register;
       private static final Pattern EMAIL_PATTERN = Pattern
        .compile("^[_A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@[A-Za-z0-9]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$");


   private static final Pattern USERFIRSTNAME_PATTERN = Pattern
        .compile("[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,250}");
   private static final Pattern PHONE_PATTERN = Pattern
        .compile("[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,250}");
       @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.register);


        Register=(Button) findViewById(R.id.register);

        FirstName=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.person_firstname);

            PhoneNo =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.phone_no);
            EmailId=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.email_id);
            weight=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.weight);

         Register.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                sFirstName= FirstName.getText().toString();
                 sPhoneNo= PhoneNo.getText().toString();
                sEmailId= EmailId.getText().toString();
                sweight= weight.getText().toString(); 

                if(sFirstName.equals("")||sPhoneNo.equals("")||sEmailId.equals("")||sweight.equals(""))
                {
                    if ((!CheckUsername(sFirstName))) 
                     {
                     Toast.makeText(Register.this, "FirstName can not be null",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                     }
                   else if ((!Checkphoneno(sPhoneNo)))
                       {
                    Toast.makeText(Register.this, "ENTER VALID mobile no ",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                       }
                    else if ((!CheckEmail(sEmailId)))
                       {
                      Toast.makeText(Register.this, "ENTER VALID EMAIL ID",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                       }
                    else if ((!Checkweight(sweight)))
                      {
                    Toast.makeText(Register.this, "ENTER Weight in kg",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                      }
               }

            }
                private boolean CheckEmail(String sEmailId) {

                    return EMAIL_PATTERN.matcher(sEmailId).matches();
                }



                private boolean CheckUsername(String sFirstName) {

                    return USERFIRSTNAME_PATTERN.matcher(sFirstName).matches();
                }
                private boolean Checkphoneno(String sPhoneNo) {

                    return PHONE_PATTERN.matcher(sPhoneNo).matches();
                }
                private boolean Checkweight(String sweight) {

                    return Weight_PATTERN.matcher(sweight).matches();
                }


        });
```

Answer (score 1):

**For Kotlin**:

```
fun emailValidation(email: String?): Boolean {
    return Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email).matches()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

for email validation try this.

```
public boolean checkemail(String email)
{

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(".+@.+\\.[a-z]+");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(email);
    return matcher.matches();

}
```

Comment: sir please test your validation for gfdfg@+*&.com as email

Answer (score 0):

You can check it by regular expression

```
    public boolean isValid(String strEmail)
    {
        pattern = Pattern.compile("^[_A-Za-z0-9-\\+]+(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$");
            matcher = pattern.matcher(strEmail);

        if (strEmail.isEmpty()) {
           return false;
        } else if (!matcher.matches()) {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
        return true;
        }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private boolean isValidEmailID(String email) {
    String PATTERN = "^[_A-Za-z0-9-\\+]+(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@"+ "[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(PATTERN);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(email);
    return matcher.matches();
}
```

[For more validation click here](https://github.com/shaktisinh/android_validations/wiki/Validations)

Answer (score 0):

With android.util.Patterns and Kotlin it's very simple. One line function which return Boolean value.

```
fun validateEmail(email: String) = Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email)
```

Answer (score 0):

In Kotlin, an E-mail address you can validate by the simple method without writing a lot of code and bother yourself with a regular expression like "^[_A-Za-z0-9-\+]....".

Look how is simple:

```
 fun validateEmail(emailForValidation: String): Boolean{
    
            return Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(emailForValidation).matches()
        }
```

After you write this method for e-mail validation you just need to input your e-mail which you want to validate.
If validateEmail() method returns true e-mail is valid and if false then e-mail is not valid.

Here is example how you can use this method:

```
 val eMail: String = emailEditText.text.toString().trim()
 if (!validateEmail(eMail)){ //IF NOT TRUE
            Toast.makeText(context, "Please enter valid E-mail address", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

            return //RETURNS BACK TO IF STATEMENT
        }
```